# supercluster: get all markers in a cluster

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-maps, supercluster

I'm using [superclsuter](https://github.com/mapbox/supercluster) for clustering markers in react native map, what I want is to get all children from a cluster no matter what level of nesting a cluster may have.

to explain the situation a little better, a cluster can have markers and other clusters as children, I need to flatten the child clusters to get markers inside them.

```
cluster
  marker
  cluster(3 markers)

// this should return the 4 markers, the top-level marker, and markers within the child cluster
```

Comment: Try using maxZoom and minZoom props to adjust the cluster generation.

Comment: I dont get ur point

Comment: If you look at the docs there are properties called maxZoom and minZoom in options props you might want to adjust that to let know which zoom level should map start or stop creating clusters.

Comment: but what I want is to get all markers inside a clusters, in some situation u can have clusters and markers as child of one cluster so u need to flat that inner clusters to get all markers... this is what I need

Comment: Have you found solusion Cristian  ?

Comment: @javalonde yes, take a look at this: https://github.com/mapbox/supercluster/issues/201#event-7731284237
if it is not clear to you, let me know to post an answer here

Answer (score 0):

I know it is late for an answer, but this solution is for google map using google-map-react package.

1. First on initializing the map options, add maxZoom and minZoom. maxZoom must be equal to supercluster max-zoom
2. On cluster rendering use this code:

   if(isCluster){

   ```
   if(zoom>=15){
       return (
           //Create MultiMarker similar to the marker below but different infowindow style to display list of places and display text
           <MultiMarker
               key={`cluster-${cluster.id}`}
               lat={latitude}
               lng={longitude}
               text={`${pointCount} Listing`}
               places={supercluster.getChildren(cluster.id)}
           >
           </MultiMarker>
       )
   }else{
       return ClusterMarker;
   }
   ```

   }

   return Normal or Custom marker;

For cluster reference: https://www.leighhalliday.com/google-maps-clustering